# How many power cables can a coaxial cable cross?

Tags: electrical, wiring, coaxial-cable

I am running coax RG6Q to my FiOS box. I know to cross electrical cables perpendicular, but is there a limit to how many wires I can cross in a short area? See my picture: the coax is the black line going horizontally to the vertical power wires. Is this a disaster waiting to happen? Can I test the interference before I commit to this line?

[image: coax perpendicular to power]

Edit: I have been running this configuration for over two years now. I can say that I have experienced no noticeable degradation of signal during this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you cross perpendicular to the power there will be no problems no matter how many cables you cross each cable basically cancels when perpendicular.

Answer (score 3):

Not only does perpendicularity eliminate interference, but also an important point of coaxial design is that any interference affects the core and shield equally, **but in opposite polarity**.

For the second question, yes.  Hook up the coax to an oscilloscope and view the waveforms on different settings.

Comment: Well, no; the interference affects both conductors in the same direction; it's the coax signal which is carried in opposite directions. Either way the interference doesn't affect the signal (much).

Comment: Yes, the interference is in the same _physical_ direction, but the two conductors are opposite polarity in the circuit.